# Best Shopping Cart for WordPress

Tags: plugin-recommendation, e-commerce

What is the most complete WordPress shopping cart at the moment?

GetShopped / Cart66 / Tribulant Shopping Cart ?

Or something else?

Comment: Have you tried WPShopp (http://shopplugin.net/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this, after some research I'm going with Cart 66 which seems to be the hottest e-commerce plugin for wordpress sat the moment.

Comment: what killer feature can you find on the free version? I normally use eshop and works kind of good

Answer (score 1):

When I was deciding, I compared WooCommerce, Shopp, Cart66, WP-eCommerce and WooCommerce, and I found [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) to be the most "WordPress" in its code and to be the most extendable/flexible. Products are custom post types, so you can leverage everything you already know about them, etc. It's initially offering was really lacking in features like UPS/FedEx rates, but they're plowing through their [Uservoice list](http://woo.uservoice.com/forums/133476-woocommerce). It's also free (there are premium addons like different payment gateways) and works with Multisite.

Answer (score 0):

woo cart looks good but I dont like their freemium model.  There is a hole for a magento-esk plugin.  another benefit of magento is the community.  The community of woocart and cart66 just is not as active.

The ecommerce wp is fragmented so too are the communities